# How can I sign a JWT token on an Azure WebJob without getting a CryptographicException?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a WebJob that needs to create a JWT token to talk with an external service. The following code works when I run the WebJob on my local machine:

```
public static string SignES256(byte[] p8Certificate, object header, object payload)
{
    var headerString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header);
    var payloadString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

    CngKey key = CngKey.Import(p8Certificate, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
    using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(key))
    {
        dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
        var unsignedJwtData = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerString)) + "." + Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payloadString));
        var signature = dsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unsignedJwtData));
        return unsignedJwtData + "." + Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature);
    }
}
```

However, when I deploy my WebJob to Azure, I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: NotificationFunctions.QueueOperation ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.   at System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.ImportKey(SafeNCryptProviderHandle provider, Byte[] keyBlob, String format)   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(Byte[] keyBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat format, CngProvider provider)

It says it can't find a specified file, but the parameters I am passing in are not looking at a file location, they are in memory. From what I have gathered, there may be some kind of cryptography setting I need to enable to be able to use the CngKey.Import method, but I can't find any settings in the Azure portal to configure related to this.

I have also tried using JwtSecurityTokenHandler, but it doesn't seem to handle the ES256 hashing algorithm I need to use (even though it is referenced in the JwtAlgorithms class as ECDSA_SHA256).

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

It appears that CngKey.Import may actually be trying to store the certificate somewhere that is not accessible on Azure. I don't need it stored, so if there is a better way to access the certificate in memory or convert it to a different kind of certificate that would be easier to use that would work.

**UPDATE 2**

This issue might be related to Azure Web Apps IIS setting not loading the user profile as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685278/create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-net-using-an-azure-web-application-asp-ne). I have enabled this by setting WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1 in the Azure portal app settings. I have tried with this update when running the code both via the WebJob and the Web App in Azure but I still receive the same error.

Comment: Does it show the same error if you try to run it locally on your dev machine?

Comment: No, locally on my machine running it as a WebJob works as expected, no exception is thrown.

Comment: Where did you import your certifcate ? I mean on Azure

Comment: The certificate is a Pkcs8 file, which I currently just have as a base64 string in my web.config (not the best place for it perhaps) and load it into a byte array. It is the "p8Certificate" variable passed into the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a decompiler to take a look under the hood at what the CngKey.Import method was actually doing. It looks like it tries to insert the certificate I am using into the "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider". I don't actually need this, just need to read the value of the certificate but it doesn't look like that is possible.

Once I realized a certificate is getting inserted into a store somewhere one the machine, I started thinking about how bad of a think that would be from a security standpoint if your Azure Web App was running in a shared environment, like it does for the Free and Shared tiers. Sure enough, my VM was on the Shared tier. Scaling it up to the Basic tier resolved this issue.